# Its possible blob azure returning a default image if the url request return 404?

Tags: angular, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have to make a requisition (http) to blob azure in angular, but I dont know if the image exist. And this make the console show "error 404".

its possible to blob returning a default image, and not returning "error 404"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that blobs are general-purpose (they can store *anything*), there's no concept of a "default image." Abstracting a bit, there's no such thing as a "default blob" either. You would need to check for the blob's existence before embedding the blob link into your HTML. And you can do that via an SDK call (e.g. call `exists()` on a blob object), or execute a REST call against the object in question.